# Reduce the length of table using tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a latex table made using the code below:

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]
    \label{label}
    \footnotesize
    \caption{caption)}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c  llllllcc}
.......
...

\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

The table width is fine butlength wise, it cuts out the last 5 rows. Is there a way to shrink the length so that I can fit the table in the page without removing the caption?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you be willing to permit a pagebreak in the table?

Comment: @Mico I want the table to be in the same page without any page break if possible

Comment: Have you tried omitting the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` statements? They're not doing anything useful... In addition, have you tried `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}` right before `\begin{tabularx}`?

Comment: Yes, tried that but does not work.

Comment: Which thing did you try? The first, the second, or both?

Comment: What's the use of `tabularx` if you don't have at least one `X` column? Also, don't use the `center` environment with `table` – it adds spurious vertical spacing. Use the `\centering` directive instead.

Comment: tabularx can do nothing to achieve the specified width if you do not use an X column.

Comment: Entirely unrelated, but in order to get a proper cross-reference to your table, make sure, the `\abel` is placed after the corresponding `\caption`.

Comment: It worked with all the three suggestions given above. I replaced tabularx with tabular and used \centering as well as \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}. Thanks a lot.